# Multiple foreign keys in one column referencing the same table

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a table called "Subtests" and a table called "TestSteps" (in a sqlite db using SQLalchemy) and I would like to allow for test steps to be shared amongst multiple subtests. This requires storing multiple references to subtest ids in the same "TestStep" table column. Is this possible? Essentially its a case of a foreign key list in the "TestSteps" Table. How can this relationship be set up? Ive seen some references to foreign key lists in SQLAlchemy docs but no specific examples found.

Currently when I try to add a second reference to the TestStep foreign key column ("subTestID") it overrides the original entry. I would like to store multiple entries as a foreign key list.

Here is how the tables have been initialized:

```
class SubTest(Base):

    __tablename__ = "SubTests"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    testSteps = relationship("TestStep", backref = "subTest", order_by=TestStep.testStepNumber)


class TestStep(Base):

    __tablename__ = "TestSteps"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    subTestID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("SubTests.id"))
```

Thanks to all in advance!
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the current structure that you have. You model currently implements 
[`One To Many`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#one-to-many) type of [`relationship`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship).

**What you need here is a [`Many To Many`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many):**
You should read the documentation linked to above, but the main point is: you need to have a relation table which will hold the relationship pairs. The code below should show it based on your model:

```
teststep_subtest = Table('teststep_subtest',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('subtest_id', Integer, ForeignKey('SubTests.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('teststep_id', Integer, ForeignKey('TestSteps.id'), primary_key=True),
    )

class TestStep(Base):
    __tablename__ = "TestSteps"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    tag = Column(String) # @note: just for tests
    #subTestID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("SubTests.id")) # @note: removed
    testStepNumber = Column(Integer)

class SubTest(Base):
    __tablename__ = "SubTests"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = Column(String) # @note: just for tests
    #testSteps = relationship("TestStep", backref = "subTest", order_by=TestStep.testStepNumber)
    testSteps = relationship('TestStep',
            secondary=teststep_subtest,
            backref='subTests',
            order_by=TestStep.testStepNumber,
            )
```

A sample test code below:

```
ts1 = TestStep(tag="start", testStepNumber=0)
ts2 = TestStep(tag="do-something-cool")
ts3 = TestStep(tag="do-something-groovy")
ts4 = TestStep(tag="do-nothing")
ts5 = TestStep(tag="finish", testStepNumber=9)


st1 = SubTest(tag="sub-test-01", testSteps=[ts5, ts2, ts3, ts4, ts1])
st2 = SubTest(tag="sub-test-02", testSteps=[ts5, ts3, ts1])
st3 = SubTest(tag="sub-test-03-nosteps")
session.add_all([ts1, ts2, ts3, ts4, ts5, st1, st2, st3])
session.commit()
session.expunge_all()

# query test
print '-' * 80
#engine.echo = False
for _st in session.query(SubTest).all():
    print "SubTest:", _st.tag
    for _ts in _st.testSteps:
        print "  ", _ts.testStepNumber, _ts.tag
```

should produce output like this:

```
SubTest: sub-test-01
   None do-something-cool
   None do-something-groovy
   None do-nothing
   0 start
   9 finish
SubTest: sub-test-02
   None do-something-groovy
   0 start
   9 finish
SubTest: sub-test-03-nosteps
```

I think the above should give you good intro to the Many-To-Many. However, I suspect it is not going to be good enough for you, because I guess that the `testStepNumber` might need to be different for each `TestStep`. In this case, you would move this field to the relationship table, at which stage you get to another solution:

**(Optional) Next Step: [`Association Object`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#association-object)**:
As you will see from the documentation of the `Association Object` it will be the structure to look at if indeed you would need to store more data on association level.

Comment: Thank You! This is exactly what i had in mind. And I do see the need for an association object as you have suggested.